# Vue JS - Rendering Multiple Instances of Components

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, vue.js

**Development Environment:**

First, I am using Vue 1.0 and Vueify 7.0.0 using the latest node. js, npm and browserify to compile the code on an Ubuntu machine with a local Apache Server.

**The Problem:**

I have created a custom component for `<form-input/>` which renders without an error. However, when trying to place them next to each other only one will render:

```
<form>
      <form-input />
      <form-input />
      <form-input />
</form>
```

In order to get multiple components to render I have to wrap each one in it's own `<div>`.

```
<form>
      <div><form-input /></div>
      <div><form-input /></div>
      <div><form-input /></div>
</form>
```

For reference the `<form-input />` template looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label"></label>
        <input name="" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
</template>
```

Not that it's a terribly bad problem, but it's so much easier to read without the extra `<div>` tags.

**Question:**

Is this expected behavior because each component needs its own dom element to bind to or am I missing something?

**FYI:**

I have also tried wrapping the template with an extra div tag, but that didn't help. I also do not get any compile or runtime errors either way it writes the template.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could i see the rendered html from the browser, with the Vue comments. Also, any console messages regarding fragment instances?

Comment: I've upload the source code to  [github](https://github.com/azeame/vue-form-testing) and I've also got the code up on a server at [192.241.218.211](http://192.241.218.211), but there are no fragment instance errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this could be causing the issue, but self-closing tags are not recommended by the creator of Vue.js: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1036.  Do you still have an issue if you change the inputs to `<form-input></form-input>`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this advise will work with Vue 1.0, but with Vue 2.0 this works fine:

- you just need to add for each component the **key** attribute which tells Vue to render these custom components as separate components.

```
<form>
   <form-input key="form-input-1" />
   <form-input key="form-input-2" />
   <form-input key="form-input-3" />
</form>
```